# Django ModuleNotFound For scripts

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror, python-3.6

This has been driving me up the wall. I have a Django project with the following tree structure, and am trying to run `python helper_scripts/load_professors_into_db.py` from the root directory

`load_professors_into_db.py` has the following code:

```
## TODO: FIX THIS DAMN IMPORT PATH. THE SCRIPT DOESNT RUN CAUSE OF IT
from ocubulum_dashboard.models import Researcher
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("helper_scripts/soc_myaces_list.csv")
df = df.dropna()
df = df[~pd.isnull(df["scopus_id"])]
df = df[df["scopus_id"] != 'None']
```

However, it keeps trying ModuleNotFound errors. I've tried adding `__init__.py` files everywhere, but that doesn't work either.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helper_scripts/load_professors_into_db.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ocubulum_dashboard.models import Researcher
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocubulum_dashboard'
```

The problem doesn't only occur for this. For other scripts that I want to run such as `scopus_scraper.py`, I face this ridiculous import issue as well.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "data_collectors/scopus/scopus_scraper.py", line 1, in <module>
        from ocubulum_dashboard.models import Researcher
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocubulum_dashboard'
```

Can someone point me as to how to solve this problem? I'm on python 3.6.

Entire Folder Structure:

```
├── data_aggregators
│   ├── myaces_aggregator.py
│   └── scopus_aggregator.py
├── data_collectors
│   ├── execute_all.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── journals
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── journal_scraper.py
│   │   ├── master.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── test.json
│   ├── nus_myaces
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── master.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── scopus
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── master.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── scopus_scraper.py
│       └── scopus_wrapper
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── __pycache__
│           │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│           │   └── scopus_wrapper.cpython-36.pyc
│           └── scopus_wrapper.py
├── environment.yml
├── helper_scripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── load_professors_into_db.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── soc_myaces_list.csv
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── ocubulum
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings_development.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings_development.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── ocubulum_dashboard
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── custom.css
│   │   │   └── side-menu.css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   │   └── logo.png
│   │   └── js
│   │       └── ui.js
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── ocubulum
│   │       ├── dashboard.html
│   │       └── layout.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── Procfile
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── runtime.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `from ..ocubulum_dashboard.models import Researcher`.

Or add the folder containing `ocubulum_dashboard` to your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).